# Collider not animating

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a roll animation for my character and added the Capsule Collider.Center and Capsule Collider.Height properties to the animation to change the collider's size during the animation.

It won't let me adjust the properties without changing the permanent properties of the collider. I can hit record or select a key and adjust the properties I want, but then all keys for those properties and the properties on the collider on the GameObject are changed to those new values.

To make sure that a collider can be animated, I created a new capsule in the scene, created a new controller for it, then added those same properties to a new animation. That works perfectly, the properties I'm trying to animate work just fine. Why is it not working on my other animation?

Also, I'm using Unity version 2019.4.18f1.

Edit: I can use events to change the collider's size through script, but it would be much smoother if I could animate it with the animator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured out the problem, it's somehow related to how I have my player character made in the Hierarchy. The object with the issue has one level higher of nested objects, that's the one called player. The one that works perfectly and allows me to animate the properties on the Capsule Collider, is the RPG-Character. Every component on the parent objects are identical, RPG-Character has an exact copy of every component on Player, along with their values. I don't get it, but this has fixed my issue.

[image]